# I don't imagine how to make a cartesian equation of the parametric one: $x=2 \sin (t), y=-\frac{4\cos (t)^2 (2 + 1.3\cos(t))}{3 + \sin (t)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, parametric

I know it's a downvoting question but I'm not good at math. I know that $x=a \sin(t)$ , $y=\frac{a \cos^2(t)(2+ \cos(t))}{(3- \sin^2(t))}$ is $y^2(a^2-x^2)=(x^2+2ay-a^2)^2$ but what it could be as a cartesian equation with the negative $y$ part I can't even imagine. Sorry. Could you help me?

Comment: Whenever you see $\sin(t)$, plug in $x/a$. Whenever you see $\cos(t)$, plug in $\sqrt{1-(x/a)^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$y=-\frac{4 \cos ^2(t) \left(\frac{13 \cos (t)}{10}+2\right)}{\sin ^2(t)+3}$$
$$\sin t=\frac{x}{2}$$
thus
$$y=-\frac{4 \left(1-\frac{x^2}{4}\right) \left(\frac{13 \cos (t)}{10}+2\right)}{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2+3}$$
with some algebra we get
$$\cos t=\frac{5 \left(x^2 y-8 x^2+12 y+32\right)}{26 \left(x^2-4\right)}$$
and then
$$\cos^2 t=\left(\frac{5 \left(x^2 y-8 x^2+12 y+32\right)}{26 \left(x^2-4\right)}\right)^2$$
as $\cos^2 t= 1-\sin^2 t$ we get
$$1-\frac{x^2}{4}=\left(\frac{5 \left(x^2 y-8 x^2+12 y+32\right)}{26 \left(x^2-4\right)}\right)^2$$
and finally
$$676 \left(x^2-4\right)^2=25 \left(x^2 y-8 x^2+12 y+32\right)^2+169 x^2 \left(x^2-4\right)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x=2 \sin (t), ~~~~y=-\frac{4\cos (t)^2 (2 + 1.3\cos(t))}{3 + \sin (t)^2}$$
There's a very useful trigonometric identity:
$$\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta\equiv1$$
where the $\equiv$ symbol (the identity symbol) means the equation is true for *all* values of $\theta$; that's why it's called an identity. In your case, we know that
$$\sin t=\frac{x}{2}$$
Using the above identity,
$$\cos ^2t=1-\sin^2 t=1-\frac{x^2}{4}=\frac{4-x^2}{4}$$
Also,
$$\cos t=\sqrt{\frac{4-x^2}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{2}$$
(The final equality assumes that $\cos t$ is $+$ve. In fact to be completely correct you should use $\cos t=\pm\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{2}$. Thanks for spotting that @GEdgar.)

Try substituting these values into your equation. If you need more help, don;t hesitate to ask!

Comment: This assumes $\cos(t)$ is positive.

Comment: @GEdgar agreed, thanks,  I'll add that to my answer.